# How to read a xml file in iOS

Tags: xml-parsing, ios8.3

I want to read a xml file within my iOS. Im reading it like this

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString] ;


purchasedBookXMLParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];


PurchasedBookXMLParser *bookParser = [[PurchasedBookXMLParser alloc] initPurchasedBookXMLParser];

[purchasedBookXMLParser setDelegate:bookParser];

BOOL success = [purchasedBookXMLParser parse];
```

But im getting success NO always. When I give the same url in browser I can see the xml data. What is the reason for this. How can I solve this. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did u implement parser delegate method ??
In my project what i am doing is as below

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sportsdatallc.org/nascar-p3/sc/2015/races/schedule.xml?api_key=wstdt33unpyk7sgpmjj5qver"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
```

After that parser delegate methods call i.e. as below
If u want data between "race" tag then [element isEqualToString:@"race"]

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSString *element;
    element = elementName;
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"race"])
    {
      item2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [item2 setObject:attributeDict forKey:@"race"];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{

}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
   [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```